# Is a XamDataGrid Serializable?

Tags: c#, infragistics

I'm looking into how to serialize an Infragistics XamDataGrid. So far, it seems it is not serializable.

Any recommendations on how to serialize the data contained within a XamDataGrid to an XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of my journey, I ended up using a DataSet to contain all data that needed to be serialized.
The SaveCustomizations method was helpfull and allowed to persist the grid's layout.

Answer (score 2):

The control itself should not be serialized.  Instead you should serialize only the customizations that an end user has done and this can be done with the [SaveCustomizations](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WPF/Current/CLR4.0/?page=InfragisticsWPF4.DataPresenter.v13.1~Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.DataPresenterBase~SaveCustomizations.html) method.  There are more details in the [Save Field Cusotmizations](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WPF/Current/CLR4.0/?page=xamDataPresenter_Save_Field_Customizations.html) help topic.

For the data, you should serialize the list that you used as the data source for the grid.  The best way to do this will depend on the list that you are using.  For example the XamDataGrid allows binding to DataSets and these can be written to XML by calling a method.  If you have a custom collection or list of custom objects your objects will need to be serializable.